# Input streams- Convert to bytes

Tags: java

I need to read an input text from the console and print it as a sequence of bytes. Use `System.in` as input stream directly. Avoid using `Scanner`.

Sample Input 1:

```
abc
```

Sample Output 1:

```
979899
```

This is my code:

```
import java.io.InputStream;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = System.in;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[50];
        int read = inputStream.read(bytes);
        for (int i =0; i<bytes.length; i++){
            if(bytes[i] == 10) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.print(bytes[i]);
        }
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Your code output:
97989900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

What is wrong with my code. `break;`?

Comment: Try checking for enter button press also i.e., `bytes[i]==13`

Comment: another text- 
Failed test #2 of 3. Wrong answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InputStream inputStream = System.in;
//create advanced stream to read line, instead of bytes
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line = br.readLine();

//get all the characters in the String
char[] chars = line.toCharArray();

for (int i =0; i<chars.length; i++){
    //use Integer.valueOf to get character's ACII value
    System.out.print(Integer.valueOf(chars[i]));
}
```

Or in your original code check for 0 value. `if(bytes[i] == 0)`

Comment: One issue that I have with this answer is that it is all code with no text and no explanation, no description of errors or problems with the OP's code, nor any explanation of how this proposed code fixes those errors. While this "code dump answer" may help the original poster, how will it help future visitors with similar problems, which is one of the main purposes of this site? Please check out the [answer] link, and then please consider improving it.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I'm afraid that I'm going to be a little more demanding. Best to add text separate from code that explains things as well. Keep the comments, but explain your answer in an easily readable way. Again, thanks for your consideration to improving the quality of the site.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.InputStream;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = System.in;

        byte[] bytes = new byte[50];
        int read = inputStream.read(bytes);
        for (int i = 0; i < read; i++) {
            if (bytes[i] == 10) {
            break;
            }
            System.out.print(bytes[i]);
        }
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).